# how to display marker title for multiple markers without tapping on it in iOS swift like places in photo gallery in iOS

Tags: ios, dictionary, marker

Im able to display info window of markers but can we display the info when the map loads without even tapping on marker?

Comment: Are you using google maps? And do you want to display markers info window at all times?

Comment: yes, im using google maps and I want to display title of markers all the time without tapping on them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, since google maps currently don't provide this functionality by default here is a work around. When you create your marker manipulate it as follows:

- First you create a view and add your label and image to it.

  ```
  UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20)];
          // Set label properties as required including marker Name

  UIImageView *markerIconImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 10, 30, 50)];
          // Set image properties as required including image which will be displayed as marker

  UIView *markerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
  [markerView addSubview:label];
  [markerView addSubview:markerIconImageView];
  ```
- Then you create a marker and assign it the image of above view:

  ```
  GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
  marker.icon  = [self imageWithView:markerView];
  marker.position = coordinates for marker;
  marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
  marker.map = your map;
  ```
- For reference here is my function for converting view to image:

  ```
  -(UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
  {
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
      [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
      UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
      return image;
   }
  ```

We have converted the view to image because. It takes up lesser space in memory.

Hope this helps. And gives you an idea for the approach.

Comment: Thankyou so much, This thing helped.

Comment: You are welcome and don't forget to accept the answer ;)